# Can we find a function $f(t)≥1$ such that the function $t^{a}/(f(t)exp(t^{2/3+b/loglog t})$ is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $a,b$ be two positive real numbers.

Then my **question** is: Can we find a function $f(t)≥1$ such that the function

$$
\frac{t^{a}}{f(t)\exp\left(t^{2/3+\frac{b}{\log\log t}}\right)}$$ is increasing for all $t≥2$.

Comment: Tried to interpret to the best of my ability, please alter to your intent

Comment: @gt6989b: All the terms are in the exposant of $t$ inside the $exp$ function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Put 
$$g(t)=\frac{t^{a}}{f(t)\exp\left(t^{2/3}+\frac{b}{\log\log t}\right)}.
$$

If $f(t)\geq 1$,  then $$g(t)\leq \frac{t^{a}}{\exp\left(t^{2/3}+\frac{b}{\log\log t}\right)}.
$$
But the RHS goes to zero as $t\to \infty$, so $g(t)\to 0$, and $g$ is increasing and positive, so it must be zero. Which is nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

You can pick your favorite function $g(t)$ which is both increasing and at least $1$ (say, pick $g(t) = e^t + 1$), set that expression equal to $g(t)$, and solve for $f(t)$ algebraically.

Comment: You wont get $f\geq 1$!

Comment: @pigeon ah you are right. I will delete my answer; take-away is to not try to go on stack exchange when I am jet-lagged.